# Facebook to Twitter connect is broken. Is there a workaround?

Tags: facebook, twitter, hyperlink, account

For years, my Facebook page was linked my Twitter account, so posts I made on FB also appeared on Twitter. But that function isn't working anymore. Does anyone know what's going on and if there's a current or planned workaround?